# How to get rid of VBA feature prompt that appears every time MS Word loads?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ms-office, add-in

I created a Word add-in that contains ribbon tab and some code to work with SharePoint sites. All working code including ribbon definition I placed in separate library that is shared between Word, Excel and PowerPoint add-ins.

For testing my solution I use trial versions of Windows Server 2008 R2 and Office Home and Business 2010. My Word add-in installs and works fine, but every time I open Word, I see the following notification: "The function you are attempting to run contains macros or content that requires macro language support." I need to press OK button three times for my add-in to load.

Is it possible to hide that notifications without having to install "Visual Basic for Applications" feature for MS Office?

There is no such problem in Excel or PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check your security level for macros. The setting is different for each office application. On the lowest setting, no prompts will be shown.

Update:
You might also want to check this out:
http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/168555-word-2007-continuous-macro-errors/

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a solution. I changed various settings in Trust Center: enable all macros, adde trusted location for my add-in, etc - but nothing helped.
At present the only solution that I have found consists in installing VBA feature for MS Office.